# Xamarin Android - Getting FCM Token through FirebaseApp.InitializeApp approach and NOT by google-services.json

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

My Question is about Getting FCM Token through *FirebaseApp.InitializeApp* approach and **NOT/ignoring** by *google-services.json*  for Switching between different projects under Single APK in **Xamarin Android C#**. 
Kindly let me know how could we get FCM Token from either *AddOnCompleteListener* or *AddOnSuccessListener* methods ??

```
Using following Packages,
1.) Xamarin.Firebase.Iid.70.1620.0-preview2

    Which Contains,
    public interface IInstanceIdResult : IJavaObject, IDisposable
    {
        string Id { get; }
        string Token { get; }
    }

2.) Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks.70.1501.0-preview2
    which Contains, 

        A.) public virtual Task AddOnCompleteListener(IOnCompleteListener p0);
            --> public interface IOnCompleteListener : IJavaObject, IDisposable
                --> void OnComplete(Task p0);

        B.) public abstract Task AddOnSuccessListener(IOnSuccessListener p0);
            --> public interface IOnSuccessListener : IJavaObject, IDisposable
                --> void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result);
            As OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result) has Java.Lang.Object which should have been OnSuccess(IInstanceIdResult result) but not.




Code:

After Initializing  FirebaseApp.InitializeApp in OnCreate of MainActivity.cs


FirebaseMessaging.Instance.AutoInitEnabled = true;
await FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.GetInstanceId().AddOnSuccessListener(new ClassIOnCompleteListener<IInstanceIdResult>());

internal class ClassIOnCompleteListener<IInstanceIdResult> : Java.Lang.Object, IOnCompleteListener
{
    public void OnComplete(Android.Gms.Tasks.Task task)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!task.IsSuccessful)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                Java.Lang.Object objResult = task.Result;

                // Tried Below but gives Casting Exception
                //Firebase.Iid.IInstanceIdResult objResult = (Firebase.Iid.IInstanceIdResult)task.Result;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could  you please post a basic demo so that we can test it on my side?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?